# View on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, view

I have read some books for developing the game without engine library using standard android studio library.
Books name game for dummies . He is showing how to make a card game using the view .
ex: setContentView(new gameView()); (So GameView extends View)

So ,i have noticed that cards are bitmaps drawn on the onDraw method of game View.
when i am moving a card across the board the previously drawn bitmaps are covered with the next.

Soon  i have a new approach . to make a card and object separate View classes.
and the view has brought to the front method .
is it possible to bring front previous Rect to next onDraw method?

Comment: thing you drawn first in code will be drawn first and the last will be in front of  others. there is no method which brings them in front of other in `onDraw()` method.

i may have took list of objects which i will draw in order of their indexes. and change their index based on my need to bring them to front of others

Comment: so if you really want to learn game developing , you should start focusing to unity based game projects. Which will allow you to release on multiple platforms as well. single code works on multiple platforms. consider it.

Comment: libGdX I think )))